# Thymeleaf how to "insert" fragments and html into another fragment

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I would like to create a base fragment from which I can insert content into to ensure that all content is centered and of a specific size. I currently have something as follows:

```
<div th:fragment="centerColumn(content)" class="columns is-centered">
    <div class="column is-three-quarters">
        <div th:insert="${content}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I would call:

```
<div th:insert="fragments :: centerColumn( ~{fragments :: couponList(${coupons})} )"></div>
```

in my index.html. However, this only works for passing a fragment into another fragment. I would like to pass in html that is not a thymeleaf fragment ie the form shown below:

```
<body class="has-navbar-fixed-top">
    <div th:replace="fragments :: navbar(${loggedIn})">Insert Navbar/Menu here</div>
    <div th:replace="fragments :: displayCenter(${displayText})"></div>
    <br>
    <div th:insert="centerColumn(content)">
        <div>form here</div>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"> 
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

I m not sure how to pass either the form html into the content to pass to centerColumn fragment or to include it nested inside the div.

html metadata:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xlmns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<!-- fragment for the html head tag. Helps with reusability of a css stylesheet provided -->
<head th:fragment="html_head">
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>[[${pageTitle}]]</title>  
    <!-- USE th:text="${pageTitle}" OR [[${pageTitle}]] -->
    <!-- pageTitle: GO TO Controller and check Model -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
    <style>
        .equal-height {
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
           height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it, but it kind of feels hacky. I placed the form inside the div that gets replaced, and refer to the id of the form inside the div and pass that as a parameter to the centerColumn fragment that replaces the div. *signup refers to the file name which the following html is in

```
<body class="has-navbar-fixed-top">
    <div th:replace="fragments :: navbar(${loggedIn})">Insert Navbar/Menu here</div>
    <div th:replace="fragments :: displayCenter(${displayText})"></div>
    <br>
    <div th:replace="centerColumn(~{signup :: #content})">
        <form method="post" id="content">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"> 
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>
    </div>
</body>
```